# Clicking outside and inside element using flags to toggle a container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve a toggle menu specifically using flags. I know there are simpler methods, but outside of this fiddle, it is what I am looking for.

New to javascript, but my logic seems correct, why isn't it following through?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaNFw/120/)

Thank you for the help.

```js
$('html').click(function (e) {
 
 var flag = false;
 
 if (e.target.id == 'menutoggle' && flag === false) {
     $('menucontainer').show();
     flag = true;
 }
 
 else if (flag === true && e.target.id == 'menutoggle') {
            $('menucontainer').hide();
     flag = false;
 }
 
 else {
            $('menucontainer').hide();
     flag = false;
       }
});
```

```css
#menucontainer {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="menutoggle">Toggle Menu</a>
<ul id="menucontainer">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: **https://jsfiddle.net/vaNFw/124/**

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('menucontainer')` with `$('#menucontainer')` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var flag = false;

    $('html').click(function (e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'menutoggle' && flag === false) {
            $('#menucontainer').show();
            flag = true;
        }

        else if (flag === true && e.target.id == 'menutoggle') {
            $('#menucontainer').hide();
            flag = false;
        }

        else {
            $('#menucontainer').hide();
            flag = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Also is your script in document ready? And finally take out `var flag = false;` out of the html.click event. Please use the above code for the project to work.